# Select a particular word from string in python

Tags: python, string

I have a string that goes like this

```
string = '12345_1234567890_1_someword_someword2'
```

I want to choose the very first non numerical char string that appears In this given example, I want to select 'someword'. The structure of sting is fixed. A sequence of numbers then some characters.

Comment: You are expected to spend some time trying to solve the problem yourself before asking here, and demonstrate your effort in your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
string = '_' + '12345_1234567890_1_someword_someword2' + '_'
re.findall('_([a-zA-Z]+?)_',string)[0]
```

Alternatively:

```
string = '12345_1234567890_1_someword_someword2'
pattern = '(^|_)([a-zA-Z]+?)(_|$)'
re.search(pattern,string).group(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = input('')
stringArr = string.split('_')

for item in stringArr:
    try:
       item = int(item)
    except ValueError:
        print(item)
        break
```

This code splits the string based off underscores, then tries to convert each item into an integer. If one can not, then it prints them item. (You can also save the item under the exception to a variable or whatever you like)

This might be a bit more efficient than regex, as this stops after the first occurrence, instead of finding all occurrences

Comment: Thank you. This solution works perfectly for me.

Comment: @KaV: If this answer solved your problem, please be sure to mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
string = '12345_1234567890_1_someword_someword2'
m = re.search("([a-zA-Z]+)", string)
m.group(0)
```

will return `'someword'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use only a simple split function. for extracting String part

```
string.split('_')[-2:]
```

Or if you are familiar with regex so you can use that as well.